# Is it possible to generate an x509 certificate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, x509certificate

I have been assigned some JavaScript tasks at work to help me gain exposure with that language. So I'm writing a unit test for a JavaScript implementation someone else has written. I have some tests working but I still need to use an x509 cert for testing. Since placing a file on a CI server is not an option, how can I create an x509 cert for unit testing?

Comment: Have you looked into using [`forge`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)? I have not personally used it, but they do have an example for generating a self-signed [x509 certificate](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#x509).

Comment: Not yet. I'll look around and see if its available to me. Y'know, company policies and such.